# cakephp use record values in afterDelete

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using the soft delete plugin for my EmployeesTable.php in CakePHP 3.0.

When I soft delete an employee I wish to update their associated user table with `$user->set('active', false);` within the `afterDelete()`

My problem is getting the `user_id` used in the employees table into the `afterDelete()`

I have even tried to just the id of the employee deleted and do a find on that but the examples I have seen using the `$this->id` return and error `Table "App\Model\Table\EmployeesTable" is not associated with "id"` from the `beforeDelete`.

EmployeesTable.php

```
public function afterDelete( ) {
    $user = $this->Users->get($this->user_id);
    $user->set('active', false);
    $this->Users->save($user);
}
```

I have also tried catching `$this->id` in `beforeDelete()` and passing it to the `afterDelete()` but again get the error `Table "App\Model\Table\EmployeesTable" is not associated with "id"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private $deletedUserId;

public function beforeDelete($event, $entity, $options) {
    $this->deletedUserId = $entity->user_id;
}

public function afterDelete( ) {
    $user = $this->Users->get($this->deletedUserId);
    $user->set('active', false);
    $this->Users->save($user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Cake 3 yet, but I've always solved this in Cake 2.x using that last try of yours. Problem is, `$this->id` is not a safe variable to use, as it already exists in the model and is modified during database interactions.

I'd say you just need to have a `private $deletedId;` in your model, set it in `beforeDelete()` and get it in `afterDelete()`. You can even unset it right after using it, just in case.

Comment: thanks, I did try that but I cannot get access to the id of the row I am deleting in the `beforeDelete()`. What way did you access the id?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think you can use the Event object with entities like:

```
  public function afterDelete(Event $event) {
     $entity = $event->data["entity"];
     Log::debug("all data: " . $entity);
  }
```

This will log a array inside the debug.log file, with all the data of the deleted user.